# Integrating an open source program into my own in C

Tags: c, open-source, rsync

I am writing a C program that transmits files over a network. I plan to use rsync for the actual file transmission. The rsync source code is freely available here: https://rsync.samba.org/download.html

In terms of integrating it into my program, I can think of two ways.

1. Compile rsync and run the executable in my program `execv("rsync", some_args);`
2. Rename rsync's `main()` to and call the new function from my program.

What are the pros and cons of each method and is there another way that I haven't though of?

I'm aware that option 2 means that the usual things that happen at the setup and tear down of the programs execution won't happen, and could therefore be unreliable. However, if I have the source code, it seems stupid to ignore it in favour of just running the executable.

Comment: Have you considered [librsync](https://github.com/librsync/librsync)? It only implements the actual compression algorithm of *rsync* and not the transmission protocol, though.

Comment: I didn't actually know that librsync existed. Thanks for the link I'll check it out.

Comment: Whatever you do: **follow the licensing conditions!** If linking, your whole code may becone OSS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both approaches will work if done correctly. So the choice depends on what you want to do.

But consider:

Source code is available for a lot of open source projects with a license to modify and reuse them. But it doesn't mean you should fork the source and reuse it.

*Maintenance* is major issue in any such code duplication. If you copy `rsync` source code and integrate then you have to maintain it yourself or rte-patch it whenever any bug(s) gets fixed in the actual source code and same for feature implementation, optimization etc.

In general, "Integration" may not be a simple task. Depending on the code size, this may a considerable work.

So, unless you really really need to have your own implementation of `rsync`, I would suggest to *not* go with option 2 and always prefer the standard utilities/libraries.

Comment: Hmm. I hadn't thought of that actually. It would be a lot easier if I didn't have to maintain/re-patch it. Thanks